# Is there any resource about wp8 ie10 development?

Tags: html, css, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10

I have been developing webkit websites for one year with HTML5 and CSS3.  Recently I've wanted WP8 devices to support my website.  Are there any books or blogs to learn from?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two articles that can help you:

- [Adapting your WebKit-optimized site for Internet Explorer 10](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/11/15/adapting-your-webkit-optimized-site-for-internet-explorer-10.aspx)
- [Internet Explorer 10 brings HTML5 to Windows Phone 8 in a big
  way](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/11/08/internet-explorer-10-brings-html5-to-windows-phone-8-in-a-big-way.aspx)